# How can I redirect URL in case of exception or invalid input with Sping?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a `GET` method inside a controller that get a lot of parameters. I want to redirect the URL in case of exception or invalid input and return (print to the client) the exception with addition message.

My function looks like this:

```java
@GetMapping("/v1.0/hello/{userName}")
public ClientResponse getDetails(@PathVariable(value = "userName") String userName,
                                 @RequestParam(value = "expInp1", required = false) int expInp1,
                                 @RequestParam(value = "expInp2", required = false) int expInp2,
                                 @RequestParam(value = "expInp3", required = false) int expInp3){
    // do something...

    return clientResponse; 
}
```

`ClientResponse`  is an object that contain all the relevant details and can't be changed.

For example, if someone inserts the following URL `/v1.0/hello/{userName}?expInp4=XXX`, I want to redirect them to `/v1.0/hello/` with a suitable message.

Is there a Spring annotation doing that without a lot of code? And if not, what is the best way in my case?

Comment: try this: https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at `@RestControllerAdvice` coupled with `@ExceptionHandler` annotation.
you can follow these steps to create a redirect system:

1. create your own exception

   ```
   public class RedirectException extends RuntimeException{
     private String redirectUrl;

     public RedirectException(String message, String rUrl) {
       super(message);
       this.redirectUrl = rUrl;
     }
   }
   ```
2. create your controller advice

   ```
   @RestControllerAdvice
   public class ErrorController {
     @ExceptionHandler(RedirectExecption.class)
     public void handleRedirect(RedirectException re, HttpServletResponse res) {
       res.sendRedirect(re.getRedirectUrl);
     }
   }
   ```
3. when you want to send a redirect response in you running code just throw a redirectException with the redirecturl you want to reach

p.s. you can use the same mechanism for building an error handling system.

Answer (score 1):

create a new class with `@RestControllerAdvice` or `@ControllerAdvice` annotation to handle the exception globally in Spring Boot.

Refer this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring#controlleradvice)